# iPhone SDK 4.0.2?

Tags: iphone, ios

Has anyone had any luck installing Xcode 3.2.3 + iOS 4.0.2 SDK?  I've tried on two different machines, on a clean install of Snow Leopard, and I've re-downloaded the whole 2GB package several times (I mean several, a dozen perhaps).  Yet installation immediately fails for me every time.  Here's what I got from the Console:

```
PackageKit: ----- Begin install -----

PackageKit: Install Failed: PKG: extracting "com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsLeo"
Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=110 UserInfo=0x350e9a0 "An error occurred while extracting files from the package “DeveloperTools.pkg”." Underlying Error=(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 "The file couldn’t be opened because it isn’t in the correct format.") {
    NSFilePath = "/var/folders/zz/zzzivhrRnAmviuee+++++++++++/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandbox-tmp/Root";
    NSLocalizedDescription = "An error occurred while extracting files from the package \U201cDeveloperTools.pkg\U201d.";
    NSURL = "../Packages/DeveloperTools.pkg -- file://localhost/Volumes/Xcode%20and%20iPhone%20SDK/Xcode%20and%20iPhone%20SDK%20for%20Snow%20Leopard.mpkg/";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 \"The file couldn\U2019t be opened because it isn\U2019t in the correct format.\"";
    PKInstallPackageIdentifier = "com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsLeo";
}

Install failed: The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.

IFDInstallController 20C2F0 state = 7
```

Sorry if this isn't exactly a programming question.  Also, if it means anything, "Documentation" and the 10.4 SDK appear on the installation options list as having a file size of "Zero KB".  Did Apple post a borked (<- technical term) SDK to their developer site?  (mind you I got it directly from them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS SDK 4.0.2 is an update to iOS 4.0 or iOS 4.0.1, which provide support for developing iPhone and iPod touch applications and includes the complete set of Xcode tools, compilers, and frameworks for creating applications for iOS and Mac OS X. These tools include the Xcode IDE and the Instruments analysis tool among many others.

With this software you can develop applications that run on iPhone or iPod touch using the included iPhone Simulator. Installing iPhone SDK 4.0.2 requires a Macintosh computer running Mac OS X 10.6.2 (Snow Leopard) or later.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/releasenotes/General/RN-iPhone-4_0_2/index.html

Be sure you've met all requirements.

Comment: I'm running 10.6.4 on an Intel Core Duo MacBook (not the Core 2 Duo, the Core Duo), do I need to install the 4.0 SDK prior to installing 4.0.2?

Comment: Try this approach. I'm not sure. Anyway installing one SDK on the top of the other will cause no harm.

Comment: Ah, SDK 4.0 appears to be working, granted, with some strange messages logged to the console, but installation completed successfully.  However, 4.0.2 still refuses to install.

I can't say I necessarily need the latest version just yet, but I'm still open to suggestions.  Thank you so much for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing on an Intel Mac running Snow Leopard 10.6.4 ?

Could your download from developer.apple.com be corrupted?
Mine download shows: MD5 (xcode_3.2.3_and_ios_sdk_4.0.2.dmg) = 8b3e0b70ddfbd045ae34d0e9a5baa488

Comment: Hmm, mine shows 7d11d6727aeca0db80d0514e4fdd9451. I'm re-downloading the file now (again), I'll report back the MD5.

Comment: Well, now i've got 5b2cb62de98db35f4669612b08baed0a.  The same download link on the same website has apparently given me two not-so-identical files.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is only because of the file not being downloaded properly (or completely).

Answer (score 0):

in my iMac i have installed three sdk version (iphone sdk 3.1, iphone sdk 3.2 and recently i have successfully installed iOS 4.0).

Thank you